# js storing text values with their count of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, session-storage

Not sure about the right way to go.
on a large table the first column is a link
the 2nd column is a corresponding text.

the number of lines in this table is not known (result from search).

I wanna count how many clicks have been made on any 1st col's links and **store this count** **with its regarding text value.**
This look like an array of array (but with unkown nuber of line)
But I wanna keep this into a sessionstorage, meaning some JSON work..

The goal is to keep alive the choice made by the visitor if he leave the page and comes back
to display the differents counts already made beside each link.
It's some kind of cart so I need to keep those data alive until they are not needed anymore.

Thank you

Comment: We don't just code whole programs for you. So please, provide us some ideas on what you have tried so far.

Comment: thank you I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

For browsers that support it, you could use HTML5's `localStorage` API. This would keep the data you store even if the user leaves the page and you can retrieve it from there when he/she comes back. This data will persist until the browser cache is cleared. There are two basic functions in `localStorage` :

1. **The setter** : To set the data into `localStorage` ,

   ```
   localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
   ```
2. **The getter** : To get the data you stored in `localStorage`,

   ```
   var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
   ```

Some more important stuff :

To check if current browser supports `localStorage`, you could try this function :

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Generally, this HTML5 API is supported by modern browsers. Here's the support table :

- IE   - 8.0+
- FIREFOX - 3.5+
- SAFARI - 4.0+
- CHROME - 4.0+
- OPERA - 10.5+
- IPHONE - 2.0+
- ANDROID - 2.0+**

[**More info here.**](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

An alternative to this would be to use [cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), which will store values in cookies of the browser. But the recommendation is to use `localStorage` instead of cookies.

**EDIT** :

Assuming you have a 2D array like this :

```
var foo = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
```

To set it in `localStorage`, you'd have to parse it to a string :

```
var parsedFoo = JSON.stringify(foo);
localStorage.setItem("bar", parsedFoo);
```

To get it from `localStorage` and use it as the 2D array, use `JSON.parse` :

```
var foo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bar"));
```

Comment: hungerpain :
I know this , I'm looking for a way to store 2 dimensionnal array...

Comment: @user1011212 check my answer. consider yourself spoon fed :)